# I need to get NULL values in Columns if Intermediate table doesn't apply

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I am joining tables where there are two separate relationship schemes look like so:

```
TableA1    ->    TableA2      ->  TableB     ->  TableC    : <<< RELATIONSHIP A
enter code here
```

And the output needs to look like so:

```
   A1columnId   A2columnId  BcolumnId   CcolumnId
   1            1           1           1
   2            null        2           2
   3            null        3           3
   4            2           4           4
   5            null        5           5
```

If there exists these two relationship A & B , I need to see A2colId to be null for below relationship:

And the 2nd relationship scheme looks like so:
TableA1->TableB-TableC  <<<< RELATIONSHIP B (This scheme has no clue about TableA2)

How would you do the join to get the result set with nulls in A2ColumnId as depicted above?

Comment: dont know what happened to my edit, but leave it like you had before, highlight the whole thing and click the {} button to make it look good.

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT JOIN` instead of a regular join will force the table to join even if no data exists in the right table, filling in `null` in its place.  So when you join A1 and A2 you would do so:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM A1 
       LEFT JOIN A2 
          ON A1.idlink = A2.idlink 
       JOIN B 
          ON A1.id = B.id 
       JOIN C 
          ON A1.id = C.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A1
  LEFT JOIN TableA A2 ON A1.ColumnId1 = A2.ColumnId2
  INNER JOIN TableB B ON B.ColumnId IN (A1.ColumnId1, A2.ColumnId2)
  INNER JOIN TableC C ON B.ColumnId = C.ColumnId
```

if I got you right.